# Apache Camel multiple JMS routes

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I'm new on Camel, I've a question about routes. In my `configure` method I've this -simplified- code:

```
from("file:folder1")
   .unmarshal().jaxb(BookBean.class.getPackage().getName())
      .bean(BeanToEntity.class);

from("jms:queue1")
   .to("file:folder2?fileName=$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.xml");

from("file:folder2")
   .unmarshal().jaxb(BookBean.class.getPackage().getName())
      .bean(BeanToEntity.class);

from("jms:queue2")
   .to("file:folder3?fileName=$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.xml");

from("file:folder3")
   .unmarshal().jaxb(BookBean.class.getPackage().getName())
      .bean(BeanToEntity.class);
```

Now, if there are some files in folder1 they are processed regularly and the same happens when I put a message with a `xml` body in queue2. But when I put a message in queue1 it doesn't work, with QBrowser I see the message on that queue. I tried defining two `JmsComponent`, one for each route, something like:

```
cdiCamelContext.addComponent("jms-1", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
cdiCamelContext.addComponent("jms-2", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
```

but no results. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I simplified my code, anyway I need two routes with different behaviour. Obviously, when I defined the `JMS` components as `jms-1` and `jms-2`, I wrote routes `from("jms-1:queue1")` and `from("jms-2:queue2")` but again no results.
Now, setting `ConcurrentConsumers` option to 10 in both of queues, messages are delivered in both of them, but in Glassfish log I see (GreenQueue and RedQueue are what I call queue1 and queue2 above):

```
[2014-08-08T09:35:57.040+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] [tid: _ThreadID=177 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[GreenQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483357040] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'GreenQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:35:57.040+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] [tid: _ThreadID=183 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #12 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483357040] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'RedQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:35:59.032+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Session.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=192 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #21 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483359032] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DS4001: getTransacted()Session is closed:Id=8349471074929595648]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:01.027+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Session.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=178 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #7 - JmsConsumer[GreenQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483361027] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DS4001: getTransacted()Session is closed:Id=8349471074929591808]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.027+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Session.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=181 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #10 - JmsConsumer[GreenQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363027] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DS4001: getTransacted()Session is closed:Id=8349471074929591809]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.029+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Session.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=191 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #20 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363029] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DS4001: getTransacted()Session is closed:Id=8349471074929595649]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.031+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=183 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #12 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363031] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC2001: connectionId=8349471074926054656:_setClientID():JMSService.setClientId():JMSServiceException=setClientId: set client ID failed. Connection ID: 8349471074926054656, Client ID: MyID, Shareable: false, nameSpace: null Caused by:com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.util.BrokerException: conflict w/ clientID]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.031+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] [tid: _ThreadID=183 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #12 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363031] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Successfully refreshed JMS Connection]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.035+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=185 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #14 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363035] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.036+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=190 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #19 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363036] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.035+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=184 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #13 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363035] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.035+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=188 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #17 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363035] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.035+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=189 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #18 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363035] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.035+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=192 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #21 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363035] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:03.035+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Connection.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=187 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #16 - JmsConsumer[RedQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483363035] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DC4001: createSession():An active Session object already exists for this connection, only one active Session object allowed per connection.]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:07.025+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.jms.Session.mqjmsra] [tid: _ThreadID=179 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #8 - JmsConsumer[GreenQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483367025] [levelValue: 900] [[
  MQJMSRA_DS4001: getTransacted()Session is closed:Id=8349471074929592064]]

[2014-08-08T09:36:07.025+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] [tid: _ThreadID=177 _ThreadName=Camel (camel-2) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[GreenQueue]] [timeMillis: 1407483367025] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Successfully refreshed JMS Connection]]
```

....and so on, until I stop server.

I've tried first using the default ConnectionFactory provided by Glassfish4, then another one with this xml configuration file:

`<resources>
...
    <connector-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/DurableConnectionFactory" 
        object-type="user" pool-name="jms/DurableConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool">
        <description/>
    </connector-resource>
    <connector-connection-pool associate-with-thread="false" 
        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
        connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" 
        connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
        fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
        is-connection-validation-required="false" lazy-connection-association="false" 
        lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="true" 
        max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" 
        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
        name="jms/DurableConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool" ping="false" 
        pool-resize-quantity="2" pooling="true" resource-adapter-name="jmsra" 
        steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0">
        <property name="ClientId" value="MyID"/>
    </connector-connection-pool>
</resources>`

and injecting it in my app:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jms/DurableConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Comment: Usually you would reuse the JMS component unless you need route-specific behaviour. If you given the JMS component the name "jms-1", you are supposed to use that. I.e. `from("jms-1:queue1")`. If you have no errors in your logs, please turn on debug logging and see what's going on. It will tell you quite a bit. It's hard to give better advices with the information provided.

Comment: it seems you have problem with JMS component configuration, please add the configuration info too

Comment: Could be a ConnectionFactory problem? I've try with the ones you can find on JAVAEE7 tutorial, DefaultJMSConnectionFactory and DurableConnectionFactory

Comment: @Sergey 

`JmsComponent jmsComponent = JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory);
jmsComponent.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
cdiCamelContext.addComponent("jms", jmsComponent);`

initializing first `cdiCamelContext` and injecting `connectionFactory` as I said above.

Comment: I meant the part where your specify brokerURL, connectionFactory, etc